# Why my Hive cannot load local file into table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to load a local file into my hive table. I create a txt file and the path is `/home/admin/test.txt`.

Then I run this in hive cli:

`hive (default) load data local inpath '/home/admin/test.txt' into table test1`;

and I got this error:

```
hive (default)> load data local inpath "/home/admin/test.txt" overwrite into table test_acnt_cmd_hour_testenv;

Query ID = root_20231005014038_8025b234-1173-44b0-b415-fe51f9313929
Total jobs = 3
Launching Job 1 out of 3
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1694167471428_2131, Tracking URL = xxx
Kill Command = /home/admin/hadoop-3.3.6/bin/mapred job  -kill job_1694167471428_2131
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2023-10-05 01:40:51,683 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2023-10-05 01:41:19,297 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_1694167471428_2131 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://xxx:xxx/proxy/application_1694167471428_2131/
Examining task ID: task_1694167471428_2131_m_000000 (and more) from job job_1694167471428_2131

Task with the most failures(4):
-----
Task ID:
  task_1694167471428_2131_m_000000

URL:
  http://xxx:xxx/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1694167471428_2131&tipid=task_1694167471428_2131_m_000000
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:271)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.<init>(HadoopShimsSecure.java:217)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:345)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:719)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$TrackedRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:176)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:445)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:350)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:178)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1899)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:172)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:257)
  ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/admin/test.txt does not exist
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:915)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:1236)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:905)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:462)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:188)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:581)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.lambda$openFileWithOptions$0(ChecksumFileSystem.java:1109)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.LambdaUtils.eval(LambdaUtils.java:52)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.openFileWithOptions(ChecksumFileSystem.java:1107)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$FSDataInputStreamBuilder.build(FileSystem.java:4913)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:122)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.<init>(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:99)
  ... 16 more


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

I am sure that the test.txt file exists in my local system. And insert or select can run normally. I am using hive-3.1.3, zookeeper-3.8.2, hadoop-3.3.6, hbase-2.5.5. So is there anyone who has come up with similar situations? Thanks!

I tried to Google but find nothing helpful. I use `local inpath` and my file is in the local system. I changed the permission of that txt to 777 but does not work.

Comment: You cloud try to put the `test.txt` into hdfs first, then do the `local inpath`

Comment: There seems to be confusion on what local means.... Hive runs distributed in a yarn cluster. Does every machine have the exact same file path available? You can look at the yarn UI to see exactly what server throws the error